# Table row with a background set will not change background when you hover over it

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the table rows which have a background set will not change color. How can I change that.

```css
.hover:hover {
  background-color: #dfdfb8 !important;
}

.background {
  background-color: white
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="hover">
  <tr>
    <td>
      some text
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="background">
    <td>
      some text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea works but you have to put the hover class on the `<tr>` element

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <style>
    .hover:hover { background-color:#dfdfb8 !important; }
    .background { background-color:white}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr class="hover">
      <td>
        some text
      </td>
    </tr>
      <tr class="background">
        <td >
          some text
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.hover` targets the `table` element and not its rows. So the `!important` will not force `tr`s to inherit the background since they have a background property of their own. Either you make them always inherit the background from their table parent, either you target them explicitly:

```css
.hover:hover tr {
  background-color: #dfdfb8 !important;
}

.background {
  background-color: white
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="hover">
  <tr>
    <td>
      some text
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="background">
    <td>
      some text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's because you need to target the `td` IN the `tr` only when the `tr` is hovered. You can do that like this:

```
.tr:hover td {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

or with your class:

```
table.hover .tr:hover td {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

If you see 'empty spaces' between the cells you will also need to add

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```